# Spring Kafka 2.2.2 Consumer returns only one record instead of max-poll-records

Tags: spring-kafka, consumer

We are using Spring Kafka 2.2.2 Release to retrieve records from Kafka using @KafkaListener and with the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.  We have configured the max-poll-records to 5, however it always gives only 1 record in the list to the consumer instead of 5 records.

Whilst with the same configuration, it works in Spring Kafka 2.1.4.Release.

Here is our application.yml configuration:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    consumer:
      enable-auto-commit: false
      max-poll-records: 5
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: group_id
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: com.gap.cascade.li.data.xx.xx.CustomDeserialiser
```

Here is our ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory:

```
  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setBatchListener(true);

    return factory;
  }
```

Are we missing any configuration which needs to be done for Spring Kafka 2.2.2 Release?

Comment: Show your @KafkaListener method.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a listener

```
@KafkaListener(...)
public void listen(List<...> data) {
    ...
}
```

Setting `factory.setBatchListener(true);` should work for you (as long as there is more than one record ready).

You can also use the boot property

```
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      type: batch
```

to do the same thing; avoiding the need to declare your own factory.

If you turn on DEBUG logging, the container will log how many records are returned by the poll. You can also set `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` to influence how many records are returned if only one is immediately ready...

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      enable-auto-commit: false
      properties:
        fetch.min.bytes: 10000
        fetch.max.wait.ms: 2000
    listener:
      type: batch
```

BTW, the current 2.2.x release is 2.2.7 (boot 2.1.6).

Comment: Thanks Gary, It works now even in Spring Kafka latest version. However, we see a small issue, sometimes it returns 1 record or 2 records irrespective of the batch size.